# In Atom, with Typescript, what does the underlined "module" supposed to tell me?

Tags: typescript, atom-editor

See how 'fs' is underlined? When I hover over it it says "module". It confused me because it looked like an error.

[image: /Users/pitosalas/Desktop/Screen Shot 2015-07-01 at 8.22.07 PM.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I hover over it it says "module". It confused me because it looked like an error.

We underline these to denote that these are *paths* we understand. And these are paths we will provide autocomplete for.

It looks like an error because your color scheme has text as *red*. In others it will look different based on the color scheme for `strings`.